# Symbol undefined in IE11 using babel

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

Using `grunt` with a `babel` task throws following error in IE11: *'symbol' is undefined*. Where does the error come from? I tried different babel presets but none of them are working. It is working on all browsers except on IE. Is it a bug of Babel or a mistake on my part? (The iterator and its variables are automatically created by babel). The presets `es2015-ie` and `es2015` are both not working.

```
var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
var _didIteratorError = false;
var _iteratorError = undefined;

try {
    for (var _iterator = chart_df[site_id][Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
        chartData = _step.value;

        sortedCharts[chartData.ranking] = chartData;
    }

    // Removes empty slots from array
} catch (err) {
    _didIteratorError = true;
    _iteratorError = err;
} finally {
    try {
        if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return) {
            _iterator.return();
        }
    } finally {
        if (_didIteratorError) {
            throw _iteratorError; <-- UNDEFINED IN IE11
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IE doesn't support `Symbol`. Check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Browser_compatibility). You need to configure babel so that it spits IE compatible code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! What is a best practice babel-config to work on the most browsers ?

Comment: if i use es2015-ie i get the same error